# Query Builder with multiple entry points

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have different filters I want to use for my model, but they are all optional.

```
if($foo) {
    $model = Model::where('id', 1);
}
if($bar) {
   $model = $model->where('age', 3);
}
```

So this code will only run if the first statement will success.

```
$model = Model::where('id', '<>', -1);
if($foo) {
    $model->where('id', 1);
}
if($bar) {
   $model->where('age', 3);
}
```

This would work, but it's dirty :(

So is it possible to save the Model to a variabel so I don't have to make a static call inside all if statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_query

https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_when

```
Model::query()->when($foo, function ($query) {
    $query->where('id', 1);
})->when($bar, function ($query) {
    $query->where('age', 3);
});
```

Comment: I only added the `id <> -1` so I have a static call at the beginning so it's still dirty

Comment: `Model::query()` to get the query builder

Comment: If you would replace this with the first row i would set this answer as the correct one.

Comment: Just keep in mind that when a $var equals to 0, e.g string "0" it will cast to boolean false and the WHERE will not be performed

Answer (score 1):

You could make your filters in a where function, this will group them all together nicely.

For example:

```
$models = Model::where(function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('id', '<>' -1);

    if ($request->has('id')
        $quer->where('id', $request->id);

    if ($request->has('age'))
        $query->where('age', $request->age);

})->get();
```